# No retorno chamar função para executar uma consulta no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso fazer uma consulta no meu BD ao retornar de um `insert`, mas não estou conseguindo implementar a mesma. Tenho isso no retorno:

```
        $.post(
        'GravaFase.php',
        params,
        function( json, textStatus, jQxhr )
        {               
            if (json.status != "ERRO") {
                var msg = '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">' + json.msg + '</div>' ;
            } else {
                var msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + json.msg + '</div>' ;
            }
            $("#resultado-fase").html(msg); 

            // APÓS CARREGAMENTO COMPLETO DA PÁGINA
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#resultado-tabela").load("DetalhesContrato.php", {IdContrato: 34});
            });     

        },
        'json'
    )
```

Não gostaria de recarregar a página novamente, somente passar o parâmetro e executar uma select, estou usando o `load`. Existe algo que possa ser feito?

Comment: Não percebo a tua pergunta. Estás com problemas no PHP ou no JavaScript/jQuery? Esse código que colocaste está incompleto, o que tem `params` por exemplo?

Comment: Olá @Sergio, preciso ao retornar da gravação de um registro fazer um select para atualizar uma tabela que tenho e não vejo a necessidade de ficar montando a tabela com o resultados inseridos, a ideia então seria ai retornar do insert fazer esse select por meio de uma chamada de função, mas não consegui.

Comment: não é necessário utilizar `$(document).ready(function() {` dentro da *callback*, pois quando essa função é chamada a página já está pronta (totalmente carregada)

Comment: Olá @Sanção, obrigado por ter respondido, me diga uma coisa, nesse exemplo que fiz acima a página está sendo totalmente carregada na div "resultado-tabela", como posso carregar a mesma sem ser na div?

Comment: Sim, já dei um olhada na função .load() mas meu problema é a mensagem que dou ao usuário no retorno, fiz algo assim:
window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 5000);